# Automatically create a record when user clicks "New" button?

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger, after-trigger

Is it possible to automatically create a new record with default values (also restricting few fields from Layout) when User clicks on the New button to create a new record?
Here I am considering regular console or classic layout page and NOT Visualforce page(from VF page it would be easily possible to control auto-creation of record.

Comment: Hi Sandeep, welcome to SFSE. Isn't that what the "new" button does already? I am afraid I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: Did you mean auto create a record without clicking on Save button? Clarify your requirement.

Comment: Yes. So when the user clicks the New button, new record should automatically be created with some default values and not asking user to click on "save" button to actually save the record.

Comment: That can be done but not without customisation and I wouldn't recommend doing that. User should know when an action is being taken otherwise it confuses them. However it is your requirement and you understand it better so you can do it but either with a VF page or screen flow launched via a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this absolutely can be done, and it doesn't take very much customization. You would just need to override the standard New button with a Visualforce page. The page would then call a controller method to create the new record immediately and return the pageReference to view the newly-created record. As this isn't a very typical approach however I would suggest scrutinizing the requirement to see if there is a better way to resolve the core problem, if it hasn't been already.

Sample code below for a custom Form__c object:

Page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Form__c" extensions="CreateDefault" action="{!newForm}"/>
```

Controller:

```
public class CreateDefault
{
    public CreateDefault (apexPages.standardController cont){}
    public pageReference NewForm()
    {
        Form__c f = new Form__c();
        // defaults will load into the record on insert
        insert f;

        pageReference page = new pageReference('/' + f.Id);
        page.setRedirect(true);
        return page;
    }
}
```